# Cannot upload files bigger than 10MB

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to let user upload up to 30MB max but the server hangs not even produce an error. Not even error in browser network bar in inspection. I did changes below after reading whole lot of info on Internet but no luck so far. Anyone knows what else I can do?

Thanks in advance

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value post_max_size 40M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 350M
    php_value max_execution_time 1200
    php_value max_input_time 1200
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/php5/{cli,fpm}/php.ini**

```
post_max_size 40M
upload_max_filesize 35M
max_execution_time 1200
max_input_time 1200
```

**RESTART:**

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Do you have the php suhosin patch installed? Ubuntu defaults to this security patch. I personally had issues with uploading large files and  had to also change the suhosin configuration in order for things to work.

Comment: Yes we have it I just checked it.

Comment: Any reason for down-voting - whoever it is? I did the researches and came up with the work I've listed above so if this info is not enough or the reason for down-voting then what it is? Please explain.

Comment: Question looks legitimate on my end, so I up-voted.

Comment: @andreimarinescu - Thank you very much for that. I wish the person who did it could be constrictive and tell us why OP wasn't good so I could take it into account if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For others who could face this issue, there could be also Apache's ModSecurity setting `SecRequestBodyLimit` (in case of using Apache) and in system log you'll get the following error:

```
ModSecurity: Request body (Content-Length) is larger than the configured limit (10485760)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is the maximum post size set in the PHP Suhosin security patch. This complements the settings in your php.ini and might cause the issues that you're seeing. A similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/486134/php-cant-increase-maximum-upload-limit

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: memory_limit in php.ini is 512M . My `phpinfo()` also prints this: _This server is protected with the Suhosin Patch 0.9.10_ I followed this [post](cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/) as well as your link to deal with suhosin.ini but there is no such file, neither anything related to it in php.ini files

Comment: Indeed, I also can't find suhosin.ini in my configuration files, digging around for it, I'll let you know exactly where it is.

Comment: @MadMax It seems you can change suhosin settings straight from php.ini, or create a separate ini file and load it dynamically from conf.d. My suggestion would be to add the tweaked parameters mentioned in the article in the php.ini files and reload apache / php5-fpm if used.